# Architecture of retries in a .NET service

Tags: c#, .net, exception, architecture, transactions

I need to create a simple .NET service. It reads records from a single table in a sourceDB, calls a WCF service for each record, and inserts the record in a single table in a targetDB. All records in sourceDB have a creation time. There is separate batch process that populates sourceDB periodically.

How do I make my service bulletproof - able to process all records in sourceDB, no matter temporary outages, e.g. the WCF service beeing down? Are there any architecture patterns I can apply?

Comment: Keep a variable with the LastImportedCreationTime of the most current record you've processed through the WCF service. Only update this when you have successfully exported the record. Then when your service runs in a loop, only select out records > LastImportedCreationTime. That way if there was an outage for a few hours, it would catch up all the missed records because it queries from the last record that was successfully processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly). It enables you to write code like this:

```
Policy
    .Handle<TimeoutException>()
    .Retry(3, (exception, retryCount, context) =>
    {
        //access your DB(s)
    });
```